# undefined reference to `Base::staticVar'

Tags: c++

Хотел поэкспериментировать с кодом из [вопроса](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1390913/are-static-variables-in-a-base-class-shared-by-all-derived-classes) на SO.

http://ideone.com/CIYA8i

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base { public: static int staticVar; };

class DerivedA : public Base {};
class DerivedB : public Base {};

int main()
{
    DerivedA::staticVar = 1;
    DerivedB::staticVar = 2;

    cout << DerivedA::staticVar << ' ' << DerivedB::staticVar << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Возникает ошибка

> /home/ZzCHQ7/ccFrP214.o: In function `main':
>   prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to `Base::staticVar'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Насколько я понимаю, компилятор интерпретирует `static int staticVar;` не как создание переменной, а как объявление внешней переменной.

Пытался исправить [так](//ideone.com/yvLrdh):

```
class Base { public: static int staticVar; };
Base::staticVar(0);
```

> prog.cpp:5:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion  before '(' token
>    Base::staticVar(0);
>            ^

и [так](//ideone.com/ggCEIp)

```
class Base { public: static int staticVar; };
Base::staticVar = 0;
```

> prog.cpp:5:7: error: 'staticVar' in 'class Base' does not name a type
>    Base::staticVar = 0;
>         ^

Как же правильно записать эту конструкцию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так:

```
class Base { public: static int staticVar; };
int Base::staticVar = 3;
```

> Насколько я понимаю, компилятор интерпретирует static int staticVar;
>   не как создание переменной, а как объявление внешней переменной.

Это декларация (объявление) объекта, а нужна ещё его дефиниция (определение). Если бы этого требования не было (т.е. декларация была бы определением сразу), то в каждом модуле (cpp, в который включён заголовок) определялась бы новая статическая переменная, и это было бы нарушение ODR. Поэтому статические объекты класса нужно определять вне класса, в cpp файле.

Comment: @Qwertiy, что мимо? Сравните Ваш код и мой. Найдите отличия. Присвоить точно так же как в любом другом месте.

Comment: Упс.. Тип забыл. http://ideone.com/Wh2oYi - да, всё работает. Спасибо!